# How to write java code to send email in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to write a selenium test by java. When the test is finished, the program will automatically send email to me. The email is also sended whenever errors occur. How can I do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should try by yourself first and then come back with question on something you did that doesn't work. This forum is not to provide code samples.

Comment: Yes, I know. My question means that I need some solutions here. I cannot start from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail sending has nothing to do with selenium.You have to write your separate java function for sending mail.You can call that function as per your requirement.For example if you want to send mail after test case execution is finished then you can call that function in tearDown method of your test class.

Comment: I've done successfully. Thanks for your suggestion:))

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the JavaMail API?

If you have some money to spare, I suggest getting this **extremely** helpful book :

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007218.do

Java Network Programming 3rd Edition.

It has a whole chapter on javamail but if you are looking for a free resource, then using google to search "java mail" might help. I don't think you need selenium at all. I found these google links for you (which are the first 3 links):

http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2001/jw-1026-javamail.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Using java mail you can easily create a simple command line program, or even a GUI to send your emails.